# How to switch cases by scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I switch case by scrolling, and make it so that whenever you scroll up it changes cases one direction, and when you scroll down it changes the cases in the other direction? I hope that makes sense.

Here is how I did what I want to do using hotkeys, but this time I don't want to use hotkeys, I want to use the scrolling feature (I don't mean clicking on the scroll)

```
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (ws) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            // T
            case 84:
                if (player.items[ITEM_TYPE.WINDMAIL]) ws.send("42[\"5\"," + player.items[ITEM_TYPE.WINDMAIL].id + ",null]");
                break;

            // G
            case 71:
                e.stopPropagation();
                if (player.items[ITEM_TYPE.SPIKES]) ws.send("42[\"5\"," + player.items[ITEM_TYPE.SPIKES].id + ",null]");
                break;

            // Z
            case 90:
                e.stopPropagation();
                if (player.items[ITEM_TYPE.EXTRAS]) ws.send("42[\"5\"," + player.items[ITEM_TYPE.TURRET].id + ",null]");
                break;

            // F
            case 70:
                e.stopPropagation();
                if (player.items[ITEM_TYPE.PITTRAP]) ws.send("42[\"5\"," + player.items[ITEM_TYPE.PITTRAP].id + ",null]");
                break;

        }
    }
}, true);
```

and that works fine, but I want to make it so that is possible to do the same thing but my scrolling instead!

Can you help?

Comment: There's a `scroll` event listener: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll

Comment: I wouldn't use a `switch/case` in this case, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for scroll events using `addEventListener` (documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll)

for example

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  // do something
});
```

or to capture scroll events on smaller box within your ui

```
document.querySelector('.my-scrollable-box').addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  // do something
});
```

once you've done that you can keep track of the last know scroll position to determine if they scrolled up or down

```
var last_known_scroll_position = 0;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  if (window.scrollY > last_known_scroll_position) {
    // the user scrolled down
  } else {
    // the user scrolled up
  }
  last_known_scroll_position = window.scrollY;
}
```

Comment: So... would this work?:


    `window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
        if (ws) {
            switch (expr) {
                case 'Windmill':
                if (player.items[ITEM_TYPE.WINDMAIL]) ws.send("42[\"5\"," + player.items[ITEM_TYPE.WINDMAIL].id + ",null]");
                break;
                
            }           
       }
     }, true);`

Keep in mind this is only for one of cases

Comment: I have no idea what `ws` and `expr` are so I cannot answer that without more context.. you seem to really want to use a switch statement. why is that?

Comment: also, what are you trying to do? you really haven't provided much context here